# AWS Sagemaker | region specific security credentials for endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am new to AWS infra and currently doing some POC/Feasibility for new work.

So I have created a S3 bucket in Ireland server, train and publish Sagemaker endpoint in Ireland server and its giving result in Jupyter notebook there. Now I want to use that endpoint in my browser javascript library to show some graphics. When I try to test my endpoint in Postman then its giving region specific error

```
 {
        "message": "Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'us-east-1'. 
Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'sagemaker'. "
 }
```

My AWS account is not yet enterprise managed so I am using as 'root user', Whenever I go to my profile>Security_Credential page and generate any security credential then it always create for 'us-east-1' region, As Sagemaker is region specific service, I am not able to find the way to create region specific security key for root user, can someone please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an IAM role first that defines what should be permitted (mainly calling the invoke-endpoint API call for SageMaker runtime). Then you should create an IAM user, add the above role to that user, and then generate credentials that you can use in your Postman to call the service. Here you can find some details about the IAM role for SageMaker that you can use in this process: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/using-identity-based-policies.html

A popular option to achieve external access to a SageMaker endpoint, is to create an API Gateway that calls a Lambda Function that is then calling the invoke-endpoint API. This chain is giving you various options such as different authentication options for the users and API keys as part of API-GW, processing the user input and inference output using API-GW and Lambda code, and giving the permission to call the SageMaker endpoint to the Lambda function. This chain removes the need for the credentials creation, update and distribution.

Comment: Thanks Guy, now I almost know the complete flow and using directly sagemaker endpoint is not recommendable, Even I am starting exporting flask too but  thanks for connecting the dot and its really very helpful.